# Testing IN-APP PURCHASE With Another account on same device

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

Good day.I have implemented the in-app purchase flow in my application,added everything necessary to the console but i am failing to test it.Issue is that the android i dont know why uses the non-testing account (developer account) as on the purchase dialog it says 'The publisher can not purcahse this item' but although i have added test account to the device,switched account in the google play but i keep getting this error.Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: you are able to test inapp products using your own account in which you added your SKU??

Comment: yes i am,as the google play gives error 'The publisher can not purchase this item' meaning that the google play in app purchase all set up

Comment: you uploaded that .apk to alpha testing and added testing account on that?

Comment: yes i did it to beta channel

Comment: you are able to check default test SKU android.test.purchased ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test in-app purchase, you need to account on https://play.google.com, publish your app in alpha version. In **IN-APP PRODUCTS**, you add products you want, add emails you want to test (only emails in the list can test). You follow this link:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: i did all that,the issue is that the tester account and developer account is only me...on same device multiple accounts....

Comment: If your current account (logged to playstore) was added to the list test account. You also need to login to you browser with your account (added to test list) and access link: [https://play.google.com/apps/testing/yourpackage](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/yourpackage) . If I don't remember wrong, you will see a a link to go directly to your app on playstore.